# BorderLayout - prevent "center" component to be "cut off"

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have a JPanel that contains two JLabel. The panel uses a BorderLayout.

One JLabel is put into `BorderLayout.CENTER` position, the other in `BorderLayout.PAGE_END`

When I resize the panel so that it does not have enough vertical space to show both labels, the centered label is always overwritten (cut off) by the label in the `PAGE_END` position.

As the information displayed in the centered label is more important than the other, I would like the centered label to overlap (or cut off) the label below it.

It seems that BorderLayout (and GridBagLayout as well) always paints the components from "top to bottom" and those that are painted "later" will overwrite the ones painted before.

Is there some way I can convince BorderLayout (or any other LayoutManager) to assume that a certain component should always be "at the top"?

I tried using

```
panel.setComponentZOrder(label1, 1);
panel.setComponentZOrder(label2, 0);
```

but that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use a custom variation of `GridLayout` that respects preferred sizes. [`PreferredSizeGridLayout`](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/08/14/layouts.html) using the `PreferredBoundable` implementation is an example.

Addendum: Here's the test code I tried. Without change, the lower label "slides" beneath the upper, but you'll have to handle the `horizontalAlignment` property.

```
public class PreferredLayoutTest extends JPanel {

    public PreferredLayoutTest() {
        this.setLayout(new PreferredSizeGridLayout(0, 1));
        this.add(createLabel("One"));
        this.add(createLabel("Two"));
    }

    private JLabel createLabel(String s) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(s);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(36f));
        return label;
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("PreferredLayoutTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new PreferredLayoutTest().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was thinking about my own LayoutManager as well, but just didn't want to go down that road. Not sure if the PreferredSizeGridLayout will help as I actually want the second label to *not* honor the preferred size. But maybe I can put something together that honors the preferred size of the "main" label only.

Comment: I've added my test code above. One appealing aspect of the design is the implicit strategy pattern afforded by the `BoundableInterface`. You might leave this open a while against a solution using a stock layout manager.

Comment: That's pretty cool. Thanks for the code. In the meantime I managed to do this using a BoxLayout (which simply pushes the lower label out of the container). But I'll mark your answer as answered anyway because I'm going to keep that code around ;)

Answer (score 2):

Call [`setMinimumSize(Dimension)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setMinimumSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29) on the top-level container when there is enough text in the center label.